# Identify if a website is mobile friendly or not

Tags: php, iphone, mobile, curl

What are the options to detect if a site has mobile friendly or not using php. Currently I am checking if the site has view-port meta tag, CSS3 @media attribute, mobile redirection by sending mobile user-agent via curl. In most cases it works fine, but in few cases it does not work.

Do people use some other logic to make their website mobile friendly? If so, what are those logics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wan to redirect for mobile, you can use mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file. I do this:

```
### MOBILE AGENT REDIRECT
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "(android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos)" [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://m.mysite.com/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Hey Nicarus, Thanks for your answer. My requirement is different. I am looking for something that will help me find out if a site has a mobile site or not.

Comment: The only way I would think you could know that is if you tried to access it with a user agent that is considered mobile by the site... It may vary from site to site.

Comment: That's right. I am following the same, but my concern is that I am not getting 100% accurate results in all cases. In most cases its fine, but in some cases the site is not redirecting and are just displaying a different view.

Comment: There isn't a lot you can do about this. It is completely up to the developer of the site to determine who and how they redirect based on user agent. Some implement it fine; others not so well.